# how to create a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navbar and I am trying to put the items in one line and horizontal.
I have to create an unordered list and create some items in it and have a link for each text:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a> Home </a></li>
  <li><a> About </a></li>
</ul>
```

then I should set the float for `<li>` to left and give a block display to `<a>` tags.
But when I do this some CSS in `<ul>` does not work such as `background-color`, can u help me with it?

Comment: can I use the `css grid` for this?, if yes I will answer by using `grid` or `flex`... or is important to use block?

Comment: well I would appreciate it if u answer me using block because i can not why my code does not work

Comment: yes. ok I will use block, I will take some minutes and answer :)

Comment: So, since you're using bootstrap anyway why not just use bs4 predefined utility classes to provide a [bootstrap nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)? If not then just remove the `float` from `li` and replace it with `display: inline-block`, or make the `ul` have `display: flex` to accomplish the same (still remove float though, float is usually not necessary)? Either way I'd wrap it in ` <nav>` element for better semantics.

Comment: If you want to work background-color attribute you should add `overflow: hidden;` to `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

without using flex or grid.

when you set the `<li>` to `inline-block` you do 3 things:

1. remove the dot before the list
2. put everything in a 1 line (`inline`)
3. if there isn't enough space, it will be `block` to like columns

now there isn't anymore the bug of `background` not displayed

> don't make `<a>` to `block` if is nested in another element that isn't... 
> a child can style the parent
>
>  but if you style the parent then all child will be

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* parent */

ul {
  background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
}


/* childs */

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- home -->
  <li>
    <a href="#"> Home </a>
  </li>
  <!-- about -->
  <li>
    <a href="#"> About </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a> Home </a></li>
    <li><a> About </a></li>
</ul>
```